# A and C class IP addresses in cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Why there are two IP address classes in my Kubernetes cluster?

```
kubectl describe svc cara
Name:                     cara
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=cara
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"cara"},"name":"cara","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"por...
Selector:                 app=cara
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.35.240
Port:                     cara  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               cara/TCP
NodePort:                 cara  31614/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.41.137:8000,192.168.50.89:8000
Port:                     vrde  6666/TCP
TargetPort:               vrde/TCP
NodePort:                 vrde  30666/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.41.137:6666,192.168.50.89:6666
Port:                     rdp  3389/TCP
TargetPort:               rdp/TCP
NodePort:                 rdp  31490/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.41.137:3389,192.168.50.89:3389
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

after master installation I did:

```
kubeadm init --v=0 --pod-network-cidr=192.167.0.0/16
kubectl apply --v=0 -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.6/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml
```

I expect one range of IP addresses in my cluster network. Am I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main CIDRs in Kubernetes cluster - pod network and service network. It seems that your cluster has pod network 192.168.0.0/16 and service network 10.0.0.0/8.

Comment: Is it ok? Or I shouldn't do kubeadm init --v=0 --pod-network-cidr=192.167.0.0/16 ?

Comment: i see no problem here as long as you don't have network issues in cluster.

Comment: I can't access pod on other node (from pod). Could it be source of this issue?

Comment: Try to rebuild cluster with default cidrs.

Comment: If  I do not set cidr then getting this error: network for pod "cara-0": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "cara-0_default" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory

Comment: Ok you are right. This issue is related with the fact that node is behind the NAT